# directly get svf from BIM360 hub/project/model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

instead of using Model Derivative, is it possible to get file in SVF format directly from BIM360 model which has already been converted to SVF or SVF2 format? I mean not using MD service at all, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download SVF dataset (no matter from your own bucket, or from BIM360), you need to use Forge Derivative API to get manifest (GET:manifest)  info and metadata (GET:Metadata) info. The info will tell the relative cloud path of the *.svf, while *.svf stores the index of the dataset. Then download them one by one.

We have a few code that demo how to download SVF data to local. The most updated one I would recommend is my colleague Petr composed:
https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils
It targets to convert SVF to glTF, but it has quite a few granule modules, one of which can download SVF data.

you could perform a simple test:

1. download the source code of the tool
2. run `npm install`
3. run `npm run-script build`
4. export your Forge client id and secret to env
5. run `node samples/download-svf.js <your model urn of BIM360> <local path>`

It will start the process to get manifest and download the SVF data one by one to local. This is a screenshot with my test. If you work with js, typescript, you could merge the module to your workflow.

[image]

Comment: ok, need Forge Derivative API  no matter what, thanks again for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

In the context of BIM360, the uploaded models will be translated to SVF(s) automatically. So you can get the metadata, properties or load in Forge Viewer directly. This is a tutorial on how to work with BIM360 hub/project/folders/item/versions, in which no specific step to translate models.
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels

Pease note: this encourages the programmers, solution builders to provide extensible abilities for the end users of BIM360, adding more values for them. It does not mean to be an alterative to bypass model derivative when the solution is not for BIM360 users.

Comment: thanks Xiaodong for your quick reply, we have a request for model in SVF file format, so I'm afraid that getting metadata, properties, etc. is not enough

Comment: sorry for my late response. when I said metadata, properties, it exactly means SVF/SVF2 :) i.e. you can load the SVF/SVF2 data of BIM360/ACC into your application (by Forge Viewer) without explicit translation.

Comment: right, svf is actually zip file, thanks xiaodong and have great CNY holidays!

Comment: Thank you! Happy New Year! oh, you meant by zip...then it will not be translated because in BIM360, it only handles the direct model format. If you have referenced models, you have to upload the main model and referenced model individually, yet by [Upload Linked Files], specifying the main model. Then load the main  model in Forge Viewer.

Comment: I mean svf file format is actually consisted of multiple files (metadata, properties, etc.) zipped together, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: well.. it sounds two questions: 1. source models are linked, package in a zip. The answer is like what I mentioned above  2. the data format of SVF. Yes, it contains multiple files (metadata, properties, geometries, cameras etc), but NOT in zip. you can find a simple sample at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample/tree/gh-pages/shaver  (this sample does not contain other data such as sql database which is another format that manages properties)

Comment: For SVF, you can download all of them to local and load them into your application (by Forge Viewer). the github sample above is exactly one demo. While If SVF2, it has not supported to download the data from cloud..while the data structure is similar to SVF

Comment: ic, thanks for the clarification, back to my original question, no way to "download" directly from BIM 360? I mean BIM 360 has already converted file to svf, just want to get it without using API (Forge), I assume it's not possible, I'll explore github sample later

Comment: Hi, I tried to explain and share a demo for you in a new answer. Please check if it helps